# Optimisation of for loop

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, optimization

I am writing some c# code that is currently supposed to run as fast as possible, usually taking up a single core at 100% for about 25min. I need the code to remain single core as the benefit of running this code across multiple cores will not be as great as running this project multiple times concurrently

The code in question is as follows:

```
public Double UpdateStuff(){

    ClassA[] CAArray = ClassA[*a very large number indeed*];
    Double Value = 0;
    int length = CAArray.Length;

    for (int i= 0; i< length ; i++)
        {
         Value += CAArray[i].ClassB.Value * CAArray[i].Multiplier;
        }  
    return Value;
}
```

This area of the code is responsible for 78% of the load of the application according to profilers and thus seems a good candidate for optimisation.

Note, the function has been changed from return type void to return type Double, this is pseudocode and not actual code to allow easier reading.

To Clarify: .net, c#4.0, visual studio 2010, target machine : windows server 2008 x64.

Edit: Further clarification: all variables in this context are public and not properties. The values in CAArray[i].ClassB.Value will be forever changing doubles that cannot be pair matched.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: What types are ClassA.Multiplier and ClassB.Value? How are the getters for those properties defined?

Comment: Programmers are notoriously bad at optimizing code by looking at the source. The only way to do this is to profile the code running on real data on the target machine. Also, look at the generated CIL via Reflector or such.

Comment: How large is the very large number?

Comment: "running this code across multiple cores will not be as great as running this project multiple times" <-- why is this?

Comment: I read once an interesting answer. You could split your array in 4 different ones and run 4 parallel processes to sum parts, and then sum the  4 results.

Comment: @Karl ClassA is a custom class defined in the project , both the values being multiplied are Doubles

Comment: @Dour I have and thus provided code as that at fault on the machine

Comment: @ErOx As far as i know , and correct me if u am wrong  running this app 4 times in parallel will be faster that running it  times in serial due to threading overheads, especially as this is a small loop

Comment: @Sebas as I stated id like this to remain single core with a mention to why in a  reply to EroX

Comment: @S_BatMan, there are a few things about this question that make me suspicious whether this code is actually the problem. E.g. it doesn't actually do anything because it's declared `void`. Your reply to @ErOx is based on supposition not data. You're not telling us what `ClassA` is or what fills it. The code shown *could* be the bottleneck, but since it won't compile or do anything, you are obviously not showing us everything.

Comment: sorry @DourHighArch the code actually returns a Double, i had rewritten the code due to : 1. not having access tot he source at the moment  2. ease of reading

Comment: @DourHighArch i beleive regardless of the task, due to the overheads of threading, partitioning the work etc, running this process 4 times in parallel on 4 different data sets should be quicker than running this process 4 times in serial across multiple cores on 4 differnt data sets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should remove this:

```
int length = CAArray.Length;
```

and replace the loop with this:

```
for (int i= 0; i < CAArray.Length; i++)
{
    Value += CAArray[i].ClassB.Value * CAArray[i].Multiplier;
}
```

Storing the length like your original code does actually *slows down* C# code (counter-intuitive, I know). This is because if you have Array.Length directly in the for loop, the jitter will skip doing an array bounds-check on each iteration of the loop.

Also, I strongly suggest parallelizing this process. The simplest way to do this is

```
CAArray.AsParallel().Sum(i => i.ClassB.Value * i.Multiplier);
```

although you could *potentially* get even more speed without LINQ (though you then need to worry about the low level details of managing multiple threads).

Comment: I was disappointed that the accepted answer (and most-voted) didn't mention this. +1

Comment: Why can't the same optimization happen when using a variable instead of `array.Length`?

Answer (score 7):

One difference is using a temporary variable inside the for loop, to hold the current value.

The second difference, probably more important, is putting CAArray.Length instead of count in the for-loop boundary. The compiler optimizes a loop like that to eliminate boundary checks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < CAArray.Length; i++)
{
    var curr = CAArray[i];
    Value += curr.ClassB.Value * curr.Multiplier;
}
```

Another thing you could do is making the ClassB, ClassB.Value and Multiplier properties as fields, if you can.

Last - remember to check the "Optimize Code" in the solution's properties to let the compiler, well, optimize your code.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    var a = CAArray[i];
    Value += a.ClassB.Value * a.Multiplier;
}
```

Comment: Only *one* index access in iteration loop.

Comment: Array accessing is very fast.  I doubt this will bring a great improvement.

Comment: @TimS.: the question is about **micro** optimizations. There is no much space to change something here.

Comment: A further micro-optimization would be to move the declaration of `var a` out of the loop.  And then make `a.ClassB.Value` and `a.Multiplier` public fields vs. properties.

Comment: @jonnyGold Putting `var a` out of the loop doesn't matter at all. The compiler optimizes the code in that way.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I did not know that.  Of course, I just do that out of habit because I'm getting older.

Comment: @jonnyGold It's a good habit to declare the variables only when you really need them - improves readability and apparently doesn't hit performance (almost never).

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a performance enhancement. If you read this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/08/13/array-bounds-check-elimination-in-the-clr.aspx; it seems to indicate the jitter already performs this optimization.

Comment: This adjustment have at best a 1% improvement, but right not im after anything so unless a better answer comes along ill consider this question complete.

Comment: Also, as I point out in my answer, using the `length` variable actually slows the code down.

Answer (score 3):

Another **micro** optimization, that *can* by the way impact on performance on very large sets, is defining a `field`, instead of `property`.

```
for (int i= 0; i< length ; i++)
{
    var a = CAArray[i];
    Value += a.ClassB.value_field * a.multiplier_field;
}
```

Even if using properties is suggested guideline from MS, it's well known that properties introduce very small (but could be relevant on very big datas) overhead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 as idea to try, but I expect JIT to inline simple properties. So try and carefully profile, swithc if see significant benifit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have much duplication wrt multiplier and `ClassB.Value`s you might want to find all the distinct pairs, multiply each pair once and then multiply by the number of occurences of this pair.

Also, I would go for `AsParallel()` and use all the cores.

Comment: I doubt that distincting elements will take less time than just multiplying every single one.

Comment: Maybe the grouping is available somewhere upstream and could be reused. Hard to tell without knowing the distribution of data.

Comment: Whilst this is a great suggestion i have stated that i would like it to remain single core , also the values will be forever changing and thus this wont be possible

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much control you have over `ClassA` but it seems to me that since `Multiplier` and `ClassB` are properties of `ClassA` you should modify `ClassA` to have a property of this calculated value. Theoretically you already have all of these classes instantiated with their respective properties already set and as such you can easily calculate the desired value of `this.ClassB.Value * this.Multiplier` at the setting of `ClassB.Value` or `Multiplier`. In that way you are reducing the cost of this loop and instead moving it towards the instantiating of your data. Is this a worthwhile trade-off? You'll need to know more about what is going on in your application to decide but it will reduce the workload of this particular function. Afterwards all you'll need to do is:

```
public void UpdateStuff(){

    ClassA[] CAArray = ClassA[*a very large number indeed*];
    Double Value = 0;
    int length = CAArray.Length;

    for (int i= 0; i< length ; i++)
    {
        Value += CAArray[i].MultipliedClassBValue;
    }
return Value;
}
```

plus whatever further improvements the fine people here can come up with.

Comment: Whilst this was my first approach, due to the value within class b and the multiplier value changing every tick before this code is run moving the calculation up stream did not speed things up

Comment: @S_BatMan:  In your approach, was the multiplication happening on the read of `MultipliedValue` or the write of the values?

Comment: @Austin On the adjustment of CAArray[i].mutiplier as doing it inside CAArray[i].classb takes the variable an additional step away from the function

Answer (score 0):

Another slight improvement would be using preincrement for index because postincrement must return the value the iterator had BEFORE it was incrementing; so, that previous value needs to be copied somewhere before altering it with the increment proper, so it's available to return.

The extra work may be a little or a lot, but it certainly can't be less than zero, compared to a preincrement, which can simply perform the incrementing and then return the just-altered value -- no copying // saving // etc necessary.

Comment: I think jitter takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parallelize it.
2. Try unrolling the loop. (The compiler might do this on its own.)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to be careful - if you often allocating really large arrays (86K+ of data) and size is different each time you may be stressing GC too much as this objects are allocated on LOH.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array has huge number of elements, something like this will be faster than other methods of iterating over the loop.

```
try
{
    for (int i= 0; ; i++)
    {
        var a = CAArray[i];
        Value += a.ClassB.value_field * a.multiplier_field;
    }
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{ }
```

Though admittedly it looks rather ugly and is definitely not a 'pure' way of programming.
But at the same time using public fields instead of properties is not pure as well.

In addition to gains from removing the exit condition, a curious bug in CLR 2.0 for X86, makes the for loop run faster if it is enclosed by try catch as Jitter in that case somehow prefers to use registers over CPU stack to store locals.

Answer (score -3):

First off, its a void, so it shouldn't return anything (or it should return a Double).  Second, C# generally doesn't use Egyptian braces - but that doesn't matter really.

Then you could try using Linq and lambdas, I *think* it may be faster - cleaner at least!

```
public void UpdateStuff()
{
    ClassA[] CAArray = new ClassA[large_number];
    Double Value = CAArray.Select(x => x.ClassB.Value * x.Multiplier).Sum();
}
```

Comment: Linq tends to slow things down.  It's cleaner, usually, but slower -- you're no longer just using an `int` to iterate; you're now making method calls on an object, which could make method calls on another object...etc etc etc.